# QuickReport composite report preview size

Tags: printing, c++builder, quickreports

Contrary to a simple `TQuickRep`, the `TQRCompositeReport` component doesn't have the `PreviewInitialState` property to control the preview size.

Is there any way to preview a composite report maximized?

*(the default state is `wsNormal`)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `TQRCompositeReport::OnFinished` event:

```
#include "QuickRpt.hpp"
#include "QRPrev.hpp"

void __fastcall TForm1::QRCompositeReportFinished(TObject *Sender)
{
  for(int i(0); i < Screen->FormCount; ++i)
    if (Screen->Forms[i]->ClassNameIs("TQRStandardPreview"))
      static_cast<TQRStandardPreview *>(Screen->Forms[i])->WindowState = wsMaximized;
}
```